# D3 Stacked barchart using JSON data

Tags: json, d3.js, charts, stacked

Can anyone with D3 knowledge help me out, basically I have been trying to get the JSON data below to be displayed as a stacked bar chart without success. For each date I want to display the reserved and unsold stock. I've tried working with examples on line without success.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "date": "2014-07-23",
        "id": "abc",
        "reserved": 10,
        "unsold": 2000000
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-07-24",
        "id": "abcd",
        "reserved": 2000,
        "unsold": 30000
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-07-25",
        "id": "abcde",
        "reserved": 130,
        "unsold": 890000
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-07-26",
        "id": "abcdef",
        "reserved": 0,
        "unsold": 1000000
    }
]
}
```

I'm using D3 within Angular for information. Any help appreciated alot.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some of your code or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @mdml I have created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSudt/4/), for some reason the bars don's show for either the dataset I actually what to chart nor for the sample data that does work for me locally

Comment: In my JSFiddle code I'm transforming the incoming dataset structure to one that worked for me, I was wondering if it was possible to just use the original dataset structure, I'm pretty much a novice using D3

Comment: OK, got it to work now, I wasnt converting the source dataset to the correct format I will post the transformation later.